# Write a loop in Teradata

Tags: loops, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm having some trouble executing some macros in TERADATA. I have one big macro that includes 3 other macros. It looks like this:

```
create MACRO D_RISK_SANDBOX.saldo_pagos(fecha_desde date, fecha_hasta date, fecha_fin_desde date, fecha_fin_hasta date)
as
(
 exec D_RISK_SANDBOX.saldo ( :fecha_desde,:fecha_hasta);
 exec D_RISK_SANDBOX.pagos_cuotas( :fecha_desde,:fecha_hasta,:fecha_fin_desde,:fecha_fin_hasta);
 exec D_RISK_SANDBOX.pagos_refin( :fecha_desde,:fecha_hasta,:fecha_fin_desde,:fecha_fin_hasta);
)

exec D_RISK_SANDBOX.saldo_pagos('2016/08/01','2016/08/31','2016/09/01','2019/08/31')
```

Today I execute the big macro (D_RISK_SANDBOX.saldo_pagos) for each month I need. It would be easier to make a loop, but I don't know how. I've been reading about store procedures, but I don't know how to make a loop with dates. 
The dates could be in an array so I can have something like this: 
(The first column Is the date, the others columns are the result of each "little" macro)

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you ask yourself if you really need a loop. SQL is generally intended for set processing.

Answer (score 0):

General date loop will look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_1 (IN date_1 date, IN date_2 DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE DateCnt DATE;
  SET DateCnt = date_1;
WHILE DateCnt <= date_2 DO
BEGIN 
  set DateCnt = DateCnt + 1;
END ;
END WHILE;
END;
```

Calling:

```
call proc_1('2020-01-01','2020-01-07');
```